# Regarding pact provider test

Tags: pact

I am using working on the contract testing in nodejs using pact, following are my queries,

1. Pact provider tests are displaying twice in my console, meaning test is repeating 2 times when I execute my pact verification test.
2. I have enabled the "publishVerificationResult" to true and given my provider version. After running the provider test, I could see a message "INFO: Publishing verification result [success: true, providerApplicationVersion: 0.0.50]" , but it's not posting the status in pact broker.
3. Assume that my scenario is, (Given section nothing but the state given in consumer test)

Given I have a student id
When I search student information by student id
Then I should get a success response with student information

How can I pass the state for this scenario, when I run my pact provide test???

Please clarify....

Comment: Please provide example code, we can't give you any advice in it's current state

Comment: Vanilla setup indeed gives doubled output from `pact:verify`